# query to retrieve data from mysql in list of maps

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query in MYSQL . I have a table called `student_data`. It has 4 columns.

```
student_data_id
student_id
course_name
registerd_time
```

I am trying to retrieve courses registered for each student. I used the following query.

```
select 
    student_id,course_name from student_data 
where 
    student_id IN(2224508,22260211) and 
    course_name IN('Java','Salesforce','Unix','VBScript') and 
    registered_time > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
group by student_id,course_name;
```

I am getting the following the output:

```
2224508     Java
2224508     Salesforce
2224508     Unix
22260211    Java
22260211    Salesforce
22260211    VBScript
```

I am trying to get the output in this format:

```
2224508     Java,Salesforce,Unix
22260211    Java,Salesforce,VBScript
```

How to write a query or JDBC template to get the above format?

Answer (score 2):

The function GROUP_CONCAT concats a GROUP (in this case student_id) with a default separator ,

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet

select 
     student_id
   , GROUP_CONCAT(course_name)
from student_data 
where 
    student_id IN(2224508,22260211) and 
    course_name IN('Java','Salesforce','Unix','VBScript') and 
    registered_time > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
group by student_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
select student_id
      ,GROUP_CONCAT(course_name) 
from student_data 
where student_id IN(2224508, 22260211) 
and course_name IN('Java','Salesforce','Unix','VBScript') 
and registered_time > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
group by student_id;
```

Comment: It worked for me . Thank you so much for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
select 
    student_id,group_concat(course_name) 
from student_data 
where 
    student_id IN(2224508,22260211) and 
    course_name IN('Java','Salesforce','Unix','VBScript') and 
    registered_time > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
group by student_id;
```